# An otherwise-valid question was closed because it was posted by a suspended user; is there any reason I can't repost a similar question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112439/43484) asked something I myself would like to know. Unfortunately, it was closed for purely administrative reasons -- viz., because (per a diamond mod's comment) the querent was a suspended user posting via a sockpuppet account -- before receiving any answers. A look through the Help files and a search on meta haven't revealed anything suggesting the question can't simply be reposted... but no one has reposted it. And confusingly, Stack has it categorized as closed for being off-topic. Am I missing something? Can I just repost the question myself?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go ahead! But please make sure not to just cut-and-paste, and that you *do* have this problem yourself (so that you are able to meaningfully answer any comments to clarify the question). Ask your own question in your own words, and all will be good.

Answer (score 11):

Go ahead; we'll probably delete the original after you do.